# BrokenProcessPool on using n_jobs parameter in cross_val_score

Tags: python, keras, multiprocessing

I'm getting error when using `n_jobs = -1` as a parameter in  `sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score`. I'm a beginner in Deep Learning and ANN and as per the instructor in [this](https://www.udemy.com/deeplearning/) course in k-fold Cross-Validation, use `n_jobs = -1` to use all the processors of CPU so as to reduce the time but it's throwing an error in my case.

Error -

> > BrokenProcessPool: A task has failed to un-serialize. Please ensure that the arguments of the function are all picklable.

Full stack trace can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/wscHkN8H).

```
import keras
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
def build_classifier():
    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    return classifier
classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_classifier, batch_size = 10, nb_epoch = 100)
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = classifier, X = X_train, y = Y_train, cv = 10, n_jobs = -1)
```

Comment: if you found solution please share in comment

Comment: No solution till now @NatiqVahabov , don't know if anyone's gonna provide a solution to this or not.

Comment: n_jobs = 1 solved my problem, but I really didn't understood why it didn't allow to use all processors by assigning -1.

Comment: I also tried that, it is working but I'm concerned about `n_jobs=-1` like how to use all processors and on using `n_jobs=1`, k-fold cross validation wasn't working.

Comment: are you using spyder as editor? and IPython console? if so, try to run the code outside spyder.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Nope @MohammedNoureldin but when I used plaidml - https://github.com/plaidml/plaidml , then I found something odd while using `n_jobs`, you can try that and give your observations on that.

Comment: I confirm k fold is not working with tf-gpu and n_jobs=-1

Comment: @3nomis that means there's some problem with n_jobs parameter because GPUs got many processors.

Answer (score 3):

Try creating your `build_classifier` function in an external file and importing it. E.g:

in file `classifier_builder.py`:

```py
import keras

def build_classifier():
  classifier = Sequential()
  classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11))
  classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
  classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
  classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
return classifier
```

and then in your notebook:

```py
import classifier_builder

classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_classifier, batch_size = 10, nb_epoch = 100)
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = classifier, X = X_train, y = Y_train, cv = 10, n_jobs = -1)
```

This solved the issue for me. Apparently, the inline function is not picklable.

Answer (score 0):

n_jobs =-1 isn't working because your gpu is off or I say gpu is not activated,u can activate it with cuda command or activate tensorflow-gpu using these links

[Install Tensorflow (GPU version) for Windows and Anaconda](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ebo8BklTtmc&t=138s)

[How to install Tensorflow-GPU on Windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HExRhnO5Mqs)

Or u can refer to this, for n_jobs understanding

[Glossary of Common Terms and API Elements-term-n-jobs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-n-jobs)

Comment: it can work on cpu but computation would be slower than gpu

Comment: Yeah it will work slowly but `n_jobs=-1`, I was using this on CPU so is it even possible to use that on CPU?

Comment: @gyrshwatson, n_jobs "is used to specify how many concurrent processes/threads should be used for parallelized routines", so, assuming you have a multi core CPU, you can use n_jobs = -1.

Answer (score -3):

i have skipped the error by using n_jobs=1

Comment: The OP wants to parallelize and n_jobs=1 would change this behavior.